# How to add new Controls (Buttons, TextViews) to a Fragment dynamically

Tags: java, android, controls

Here's my fragment class:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {           
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        EditText newText = new EditText(getActivity());

        newText.setText("This is a fragment");
        newText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false); 
     }
}
```

I am trying to add `newText` to the fragment being created.

Answer (score 0):

simply store the view that was returned from the `inflater.inflate` call , and add anything you want to it .

in the end , return the stored view .